# Ruby MongoId: race condition in callbacks

Tags: ruby, callback, mongoid, after-save

I have the Model:

```
class MyModel
    include Mongoid::Document

    after_save :my_callback, if: -> { name_changed? }

    field :name, type: String

    def my_callback
       # this will execute two times
       puts 'executes my callback'
       puts changes
    end
end
```

Imagine if the follow code is executed, when variable `a` and `b` receive the same document and the function `update!` is executed with the same argument `name: 'foo'`. So, in the first update the function `my_callback` should be called, but in the second update not should.

```
MyModel.create(name: 'bar')
a = MyModel.last
b = MyModel.last

a.update!(name: 'foo')
executes my callback
{"name"=>['bar', 'foo']}
=> true

b.update!(name: 'foo')
executes my callback -> this not can execute
{"name"=>['bar', 'foo']}
=> true
```

how prevent the function `my_callback` run in the second update?

Comment: I suggest reading about [locking records for update](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#locking-records-for-update) in the Rails Guides.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty tracking (`foo_changed?` methods) is performed entirely on the client side.

The following creates two separate model objects:

```
a = MyModel.last
b = MyModel.last
```

When you update `a`, the application has no idea that `a` and `b` refer to the same document in the database. As far as the application is concerned, after the `a.update!` call, `b` still has the original value for `name` (which you can verify).

Therefore, when you issue `b.update!`, the value of `name` *as stored in `b`* **has** changed and your callback is invoked.

To find out whether the value changed in the database you could use for example conditional updates.`[enter link description here][1]`